# How to use function parameters/arguments in this.setState

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How do I go about using the url and stateObj arguments in the getData function in the places that the arguments[?] are placed?

```js
function getData(url, stateObj) {
      fetch(arguments[0])
          .then(res => res.json())
          .then(res => {
              this.setState({ arguments[1]: res.results });
          });
}
```

Comment: are you saying in your code that if you do `fetch(url).then(...` it doesn't work?

Comment: the url parameter works but the stateObj in the this.setState doesn't and I'm wondering how to be able to pass a string in as the stateObj parameter and be able to set the state of the passed in string. @Tony

Comment: @B.Mauger `[arguments[1]]: res.results`?

Comment: @Li357 I want the stateObj param to be where arguments[1] is, was just a way to show what was meant to go where in my question. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
function getData(url, stateObj) {
    fetch(url)
        .then(res => {
            return res.json();
         })
         .then(res => {
             this.setState({ [stateObj]: res.results });
         })
}
```

See the bracket notation section at [this Property Accessors docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors)

Comment: Works perfectly! Thanks. Will mark as answer when I can.